# MongoDB (WiredTiger) Error while trying to use DBFS (Databricks) mounted storage as --dbpath

Tags: mongodb, databricks, wiredtiger

### Question:

I'm trying to set up a MongoDB instance in databricks notebook using Databricks' DBFS mounted storage as its data storage location. I can mount my storage (azure blob or s3 bucket) to DBFS and can access it without issues from Databricks and do POSIX calls with python.

However, when I attempt to start MongoDB with the `--dbpath` flag set to my DBFS-mount, I get the `Operation not supported` error:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-12T11:13:17.785+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-12T11:13:17.786+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"main","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":21},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":21},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":21},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-12T11:13:17.788+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-12T11:13:17.789+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-12T11:13:17.789+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-12T11:13:17.789+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"main","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-12T11:13:17.789+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"TENANT_M", "id":7091600, "ctx":"main","msg":"Starting TenantMigrationAccessBlockerRegistry"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-12T11:13:17.789+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":4048,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/dbfs/mnt/aws/fiftyone/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"1006-121834-gtupj2oh-10-139-64-4"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-12T11:13:17.789+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"7.0.2","gitVersion":"02b3c655e1302209ef046da6ba3ef6749dd0b62a","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu2204","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-12T11:13:17.789+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"22.04"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-12T11:13:17.789+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"storage":{"dbPath":"/dbfs/mnt/aws/fiftyone/db"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-12T11:13:18.185+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=10994M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,remove=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),builtin_extension_config=(zstd=(compression_level=6)),file_manager=(close_idle_time=600,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=2000),statistics_log=(wait=0),json_output=(error,message),verbose=[recovery_progress:1,checkpoint_progress:1,compact_progress:1,backup:0,checkpoint:0,compact:0,evict:0,history_store:0,recovery:0,rts:0,salvage:0,tiered:0,timestamp:0,transaction:0,verify:0,log:0],"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-12T11:13:19.576+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"WT",       "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error message","attr":{"error":95,"message":{"ts_sec":1697109199,"ts_usec":576472,"thread":"4048:0x7fcff4155c80","session_name":"connection","category":"WT_VERB_DEFAULT","category_id":9,"verbose_level":"ERROR","verbose_level_id":-3,"msg":"__posix_file_close:360:/dbfs/mnt/aws/fiftyone/db/journal/WiredTigerTmplog.0000000001: handle-close: close","error_str":"Operation not supported","error_code":95}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-12T11:13:20.307+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"WT",       "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error message","attr":{"error":95,"message":{"ts_sec":1697109200,"ts_usec":306958,"thread":"4048:0x7fcff4155c80","session_name":"connection","category":"WT_VERB_DEFAULT","category_id":9,"verbose_level":"ERROR","verbose_level_id":-3,"msg":"__posix_file_close:360:/dbfs/mnt/aws/fiftyone/db/journal/WiredTigerTmplog.0000000001: handle-close: close","error_str":"Operation not supported","error_code":95}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-12T11:13:21.059+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"WT",       "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error message","attr":{"error":95,"message":{"ts_sec":1697109201,"ts_usec":59781,"thread":"4048:0x7fcff4155c80","session_name":"connection","category":"WT_VERB_DEFAULT","category_id":9,"verbose_level":"ERROR","verbose_level_id":-3,"msg":"__posix_file_close:360:/dbfs/mnt/aws/fiftyone/db/journal/WiredTigerTmplog.0000000001: handle-close: close","error_str":"Operation not supported","error_code":95}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-12T11:13:21.063+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22347,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version. This may be due to an unsupported upgrade or downgrade."}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-12T11:13:21.063+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":28595,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Terminating.","attr":{"reason":"95: Operation not supported"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-12T11:13:21.063+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"ASSERT",   "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":28595,"file":"src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp","line":674}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-12T11:13:21.063+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"ASSERT",   "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
```

Has anyone any idea why this is happening and way to get around it? Any help would be appreciated.

**P.S.** I am well aware about the caveats of using FUSE or NFS on mogodb performance.

1. I have tried doing the same with google colab with google drive mount and it works fine.
2. I have tried mounting both azure blob storage and s3 bucket both with same outcome. It works fine when I use the normal system path.
3. I have tried it with mongodb versions 5,6 and 7 and also various databricks runtimes, all with the same problem with the dbfs mount.

Answer (score 0):

It's a really bad idea to use DBFS for that - the underlying cloud storage doesn't provide a lot of functionality ([officially documented](https://docs.databricks.com/en/files/index.html#local-file-api-limitations)), such as random writes, sparse files, etc. Databases like MongoDB, Cassandra, relational databases, etc. should use real disk storage.

Answer (score 0):

The operation that is not supported is fsync.

WiredTiger relies of fsync for normal operations.

You will need to consult the DBFS documentation to see if there is a way to permit remote fsync locking.